# How to see the maven commands executed by Intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, command

When run a test in Intellij, I can see the (very long) command that it uses to execute it. I would also like to see the commands it issues before, to build the sources. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Not really. It is compiled programmatically.

IntelliJ starts its own proprietary build process (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/jps/jps-builders/src/org/jetbrains/jps/cmdline/BuildMain.java#L73) and communicates with it via Netty.